# RESTAPI return syntax error despite following documentation

Tags: javascript, api, postman

## Syntax Error

I am using an API to get contacts from a CRM based on tags. I am using POSTMAN for now to test the api but getting syntax error. I am assuming the documentation has the syntax error as I am copy/pasting but can't see the issue.

Here is the link to the documentation: https://github.com/agilecrm/rest-api#121-get-contacts-by-dynamic-filter

Here is a screenshot of my response via POSTMAN.

[image]

My headers are:
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Can anyone see something here that would be causing a syntax error in my POST request?

Comment: noticed there was a missing quote around rules but this didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Issue could be with filterJson parameter. make sure that it is a json value